# Swift 3 prepare for segue is not being called

Tags: swift

I am trying to figure out where my issue(s) are in my project and I have nailed one. My prepare for segue is not working.

I have two VC's and they are connected with a segue, I named the segue and I am able to tap a button and go to it and everything works as it should on each page except that information from VC 1 does not transfer over to VC 2.

This is what I have so far

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "fromLandingPageToAddPalautte" {

        if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? AddPalautteViewController {

            print("test")

        }
    }
}
```

I've tried breakpoints and just a print statement as seen above.

On the button tap I say

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "fromLandingPageToAddPalautte", sender: self)
```

I have seen other SO posts saying add `super.perfomSegue...`

but that does not work either.

Comment: Are you using NavigationControllers?

Comment: Yes I am using navigation controller on that particular part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple fix:

```
if segue.identifier == "fromLandingPageToAddPalautte" {
    if let controller = segue.destination as? UINavigationController {
        if let destinationVC = controller.topViewController as? AddPalautteViewController {
            print("test")
        }
    }

}
```

You were trying to access the navigationController, not the AddPalautteViewController.

Comment: @VarunNaharia Revenge voting will get you nowhere. I'm not trying to antagonize you, I just want you to add an explanation to your code. As you can see, I have told the OP in this question what he was doing wrong, and then provided concise code to show how he could fix it. If you do the same on your answer, I will remove my down-vote. It's as simple as that.